# What do I need to worry about regarding HTML form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am creating a simple form using HTML and wanted to make sure I'm not missing and security vulnerabilities. I don't know much about attacks, but I was thinking there must be more for the message field, as pretty much anything can be typed in there. I could limit to text only, but thought that might not be very user friendly.

Does it even matter that someone can type 250 characters of any type?  Can anything harmful be done with that?

```
<form id="contact_form_id" method="POST" action="" name="contact_form">   
   <input class="contact_single_line" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" minlength="2" maxlength="25" required type="text" onkeypress="return isAlpha(event)"></input>
   <input class="contact_single_line" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" minlength="2" maxlength="25" required type="text" onkeypress="return isAlpha(event)"></input>
   <input class="contact_single_line" type="email" id="email" name="email" minlength="3" maxlength="45" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address" TextMode="email" required data-errormessage-type-mismatch="Invalid!"></input>
   <textarea id="message" name="message" minlength="2" maxlength="250" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="contact_submit_btn" value="SUBMIT"></input>
</form>
```

Also using this isAlpha function as a backup.  Not sure if it is even necessary with the HTML5 validators I have already

```
function isAlpha (evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode (key);
    var regex = /[A-Za-z_ ]|\./;
    if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
      theEvent.returnValue = false;
      if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't rely on client side for the validation , some nasty things can be done from client side. Secure the server side also.

Comment: Through PHP validation? It is going to a php script so I'm guessing thats what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting the maxlength in your html form doesn't prevent an attacker from forging a fake submission - that would have no limitations on what is sent to your server. So, it is of no security value at all. You *must* check all data received in your server, you have to consider it might be all dangerous. It is not a trivial task to do.

Comment: Ok that is good advice. One question though. I am using an Ajax func to jump over to a separate php to process the data. If I use good validation practice in that php like htmlspecialchars(), removing white space etc... Is that still bad that I am jumping pages like that? Should everything be done on the same page as the form?

Comment: Website security is a huge subject. I would recommend you to start by reading about SQL injections - one of the possible attack vectors - to start getting an idea.

Comment: Ok Ill check it out

Answer (score 3):

Client-side validation (HTML 5 or JavaScript) is useful only to make the visitor's experience nicer — any attacker can bypass it easily. It is used to warn visitors that what they have entered is bad before they submit it to the server.

If you want to worry about security then you need to do it server side, and it needs to be contextual to what you are doing with the data.